# Convert YYYY/MM/DD To Valid Format

Tags: javascript, date, titanium

I have a date formatted like this from a Java Server:

`YYYY/MM/DD 00:00:00.0`

And that is a format that JavaScript won't accept. So, I do this:

```
var startDate = '2012-07-27 00:00:00.0';
startDate = startDate.substring(0, 10);
```

Which then kindly returns `2012-07-27`. (Note: I tried it with the time and without)

However, then I want to turn it into a date format I can use to compare two dates. So, I preform this:

```
startDate = new Date(startDate);
```

Which, finally, returns this in the log: `Invalid Date`

So, for the purpose of comparing dates, like so:

```
if(currentDate > startDate)
```

I need to be able to get the format I have into one that will be accepted so I can then compare each of the various dates.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You string format is incompatible that is why new Date(datestring) won't work. You can parse the string yourself with Regex and create a new Date object with explicit values for year, month, date, minute and second . Look at  [Date.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) for valid format

Or use this https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC  after parsing your string 
example for your string would be

```
gmtDate = new Date(Date.UTC(2012, 07, 27, 0, 0, 0));
```

Comment: I can get the year, month, day, and time in roughly 30 seconds with `.split()`. I'll try your method

Answer (score 0):

you could use [Zetafleets - javascript dateparse for iso 8601](http://zetafleet.com/blog/javascript-dateparse-for-iso-8601)

Answer (score 0):

If you are allowed to use javascript library, you can use datejs (datejs.com) and Date.parseExact() function:

```
Date.parseExact(startDate, "yyyy/MM/dd")
```

Or if you can't or don't like to use library for this purpose you can encapsulate the custom logic for transforming this string into the proper date using regex, for example as ama2 suggested through:

```
Date.parseExact = function(dateString, format) { ... your implementation here }
```

Answer (score -1):

If your dates use 24 hour time, rather than 12 hour AM/PM, and they are always in that exact format, a direct string comparison will yield the correct result. In other words,

```
'2012-07-27 00:00:00.0' > '2012-07-26 00:00:00.0' === true
'2012-07-27 00:00:00.0' > '2012-07-26 23:59:99.9' === true
'2012-07-27 10:00:00.0' > '2012-07-27 12:00:00.0' === false
```

Sometimes the easiest way is right there in front of you ;)